# Remaining rows and percentage in Powershell

Tags: xml, csv, powershell, percentage

I'm trying to create a **powershell** program that read a XML file, and store datas into an excel file to analyse it more efficiently.  So I can open the document without problem, read the XML and write in the CSV without any problems. But when the user launches his program, i want to show him how many rows are remaining with a **percentage**.

Here is my code :

```
$Packages = $xdoc.DataProfile.DataProfileOutput.Profiles.ColumnValueDistributionProfile
$PackageNumber = $Packages.Count

# --- For each couple, get the table name, the number of rows, the name of the field, and the number of different values existing in each fields --- #

$i = 0
while($i -ne $PackageNumber){
    $state = $i/$PackageNumber * 100
    $state = [math]::floor($state)
    Write-Host $state "of 100 %"

    # Here are commands to get infos about the content of the xml 

 $j = 0
    while($j -lt $ItemNumber){
        $Value = #value in the xml ..  
        $Count = #number of the row in the xml .. 
        # --- If the number of rows in the fields is different from 0, calculate the purcentage for each value and add it to the CSV --- #

        if($table_rows -ne 0){
            $Purcentage = $Count / $table_rows * 100
            $csv_content = $table_name + ";" + $table_field + ";" + $table_rows + ";" + $Value + ";" + $Count + ";" + $Purcentage
            ADD-content -path $csv_file -value $csv_content
        }
        $j++ 
    }
    $i++
}
```

This way, i can count the number of total rows, and the rows where the buffer is reading. With a simple **division** i obtain the percentage.

But the result is :

```
50 of 100 %
50 of 100 %
....
50 of 100 %
51 of 100 %
51 of 100 %
....
51 of 100 %
```

How can i obtain **only one row** for each value of percentage and not many like below ?

```
50 of 100 %
51 of 100 % 
52 of 100 %
```

Comment: Where in your code is the logic to display `50 of 100%`?

Comment: oh sorry, i've forgot it. It should now appear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with an idea to do this.  Earlier in your script, add the line `$oldState = 0`, to give us a baseline percentage.

Then, within your main script block, beneath this line `$state = [math]::floor($state)`, add this:

```
if ($state -ne $oldState){
Write-Host $state "of 100 %"
$oldState = $state
}
```

The net result will be a comparison to see if the current state is the same as the last `$state` written to the screen.  If it **isn't**, then we write the percentage and set a new value for state.  The end result will display each percentage only a single time, while the script is executing.

Answer (score 0):

there may be a better way, but the first thing that comes to mind is getting all rows in the file except the last one then appending the percentage. in this example i add an extra line at the end of the file to be sure I'm not deleting important information.

```
'asdf' > C:\temp\test.txt

' ' >> C:\temp\test.txt
0..100 | % {
    sleep 1
    $file = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Test.txt'
    $file = $file[0..$($file.Count-2)]
    $file += "$_%"
    $file > C:\temp\test.txt
    Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt
}
```